# Oauth -> retrieveAccessToken()

Tags: oauth, access-token

I have to do an Oauth workflow. The documentation of the service that i want me to connect tell me that when i want to exchange my **request_token** and my **token_verifier** obtained by the service in a usable **acces_token** i have to do : 

    `retrieveAccessToken(getConsumer(), verifier, new String[]{"oauth_from", from, "oauth_to", to});` 
 
But i never hear about this 2 parameter : ***oauth_from*** & ***oauth_to***. What they are??? What should i put inside?
Sorry about my bad english, ty for time lost.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found what they are:
**from** is the date from where the access_token is valid
**to** is the date where the access_token expired